# ES6 Eliminar object dentro de array de objetos

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Cual es la forma mas optima para eliminar un objeto dentro de un `array` de objetos.

```
{
 levels: [
  { 
    name: 1,
    elements: [
     {id: 1},
     {id: 2},
     {id: 3}
    ]
  }, ...more objects
 ]
}
```

Quiero eliminar en elemento con id 2, sin embargo esta dentro de un `array` de objetos,
cual sería la forma mas óptima de eliminar información, sin alterar los otros niveles  `2, 3, 4, 5`

Comment: Si solo necesitas que ese objeto esté vacío, ¿por qué no redefinirlo? Por ejemplo, `levels.elements[1] = ""`. Porque otros métodos de eliminación de elementos de un array va a a modificar el orden del resto de los índices.

Comment: La modificación de los indices no me corrompe nada, con alterar los otros niveles me refiero a que salida de información sea igual pero sin incluir los elementos eliminados.

Comment: En ese caso tal vez te sirva usar el método [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la eficiencia depende de muchos factores, yo te propongo utilizar una funcion a la que le pasas el objeto, el nivel y el indice que quieres eliminar y te devuelve el objeto completo sin ese indice:

```js
var objeto = {
      levels:[
        {
          name:1,
          elements:[
            {id:1},
            {id:2},
            {id:3}
          ]
        },
        {
          name:2,
          elements:[
            {id:1},
            {id:2},
            {id:3}
          ]
        }  
      ]
    }

    function eliminaElementoSubArray(object, nivel, indiceAEliminar){
      object.levels[object.levels.findIndex(level=>level.name == nivel)].elements.splice(indiceAEliminar -1, 1); 
      return object;
    }

    console.log(eliminaElementoSubArray(objeto, 1, 2))
```

la funcion que es muy simple, utiliza un `findIndex` porque los objetos que hay dentro del array `levels` no tienen porque estar en orden, es decir, puedes tener en `levels[0]`:

```
{
  name:2,
  elements[...]
}
```

y usamos `indiceAEliminar -1` porque los array tienen base `0`. aqui tambien deberiamos usar un `findIndex`, por el mismo motivo que antes.

ahora bien, si supieras exactamente que los elementos los has insertado en el orden correcto dentro de levels y dentro de elements, la funcion se podria cambiar sustituyendo los `findIndex` por el parametro que le pasamos, de la siguiente manera:

```js
var objeto = {
      levels:[
        {
          name:1,
          elements:[
            {id:1},
            {id:2},
            {id:3}
          ]
        },
        {
          name:2,
          elements:[
            {id:1},
            {id:2},
            {id:3}
          ]
        }  
      ]
    }

    function eliminaElementoSubArray(object, nivel, indiceAEliminar){
      object.levels[nivel - 1].elements.splice(indiceAEliminar -1, 1); 
      return object;
    }

    console.log(eliminaElementoSubArray(objeto, 1, 2))
```

espero que esto te ayude.

Answer (score 1):

Cualquiera sea la forma en la que se implemente, se necesitan 2 datos, el id a eliminar y el elemento en el cual está el id que se quiere eliminar. Este último podría se un indice, en cuyo caso una de las respuestas de aqui podŕia servir : `obj.levels[indice_a_eliminar].elements.splice(1, 1);`, si la referencia es otra, porejemplo el atributo `name`, se puede hacer:

```js
const obj = {levels: [{name: 1,elements:[{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3}]},{name: 2,elements:[{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3}]},{name: 3,elements:[{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3}]}]};

const name_a_eliminar = 1;//<-- el atributo name que queremos analizar
const id_a_eliminar = 2;//<-- el atributo id dentro de name que queremos eliminar

const res = obj.levels.map(e=>{

if (e.name == name_a_eliminar){

const elem_tmp = e.elements.filter(e2=>e2.id !== id_a_eliminar);

e.elements = elem_tmp;

}

return e;

});

console.log(res);
```

Lo mismo se puede hacer con otras propiedades, pero siempre vamos a necesitar una referencia.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un filtro. Si quieres eliminar el objeto de id == 2, algo tipo:

```
fElements = levels[0].elements.filter((element) => element.id !== 2);
```

Donde fElements contendría únicamente los objetos con una id diferente de 2. Creo que es lo suficientemente decente

Comment: No me sirve, tomando en cuenta que no solo hay un level

Answer (score 0):

El método [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#eliminar_1_elemento_desde_el_%C3%ADndice_3) es útil para eliminar elementos de un array.

Solo hay que pasarle como argumento el índice del elemento del array a eliminar, seguido del número 1.

```js
let obj = {
 levels: [
  { 
    name: 1,
    elements: [
     {id: 1},
     {id: 2},
     {id: 3}
    ]
  }, 
 ]
}

obj.levels[0].elements.splice(1, 1);

console.log(obj)
```

Como se ve en este ejemplo que está basado en tu código, el resultado es el mismo objeto cuyo array está ya sin el elemento que acabamos de eliminar y que tenía el índice 1.